# Learning jQuery, but nothing is happening?

Tags: jquery, function, click

I'm trying to use jQuery, but for some reason nothing is happening when I click a button. I've tried manipulating the code in many ways, but still nothing happens

I'm using Firefox, and javascript works fine.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color:royalblue; 
            margin:0px;
        }

        #div_header {
            background-color:black;
            height:200px;   
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $("#div_header").hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_header">
        <button type="button">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work -> [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nCqRt/)

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/ymgYv/

Comment: Can you check to see if jquery is actually being loaded? It works for me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors reported in the Firefox Error Console?

Comment: Are you viewing it as a file on your file system, or through a server?  You might want to prepend 'https:' to the script src if you are using the file protocol

Comment: @danronmoon On my file system, this is the problem (see AlecTMH's post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script source value is incorrect. Change it to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I've run into the same issue before. When running on localhost in some clients (Chrome/FF) the // notation doesn't work. All you downvoters need to try and reproduce the problem before you go getting authoritative.

Comment: Yep! w3schools isn't always the most reputable source. Thank you very much sir

Comment: If this is meant to be run on a server that switches between protocols, using // will automatically determine the best way. If you're only running it on a localhost, then you need to include the http: part.

Comment: @BrandonDixson Don't use w3schools, try google Jeffrey Way - 30 days jQuery, brilliant videos.

Comment: @BrandonDixson Don't forget to tick this as the right answer.  I've learnt something new today, and this should be flagged as correct!